# How to run multiple Hive activities in parallel using AWS data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

We want to use AWS data pipeline to automate data ingestion process. In our ingestion process we mainly copy CSV files into S3 bucket and run Hive queries on it for more than 100 different tables.

We want to create one pipeline in which we will be able to process all the 100 tables.

I would like to know if we can run multiple Hive activities and S3 copy activities in parallel? I couldn't find this information in AWS documents if pipeline activities run serially or in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HadoopActivity which calls the hive query from a Java executable. AWS Data Pipeline supports parallel execution of HadoopActivities.

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-hadoopactivity.html